# Linking error when overloading operator <<

Tags: c++, struct, include, operator-overloading

I want to overload the `<<` operator for my own struct saved in its own `.hpp` file like this:

```
#ifndef MY_STRUCTS_HPP
#define MY_STRUCTS_HPP

#include <iostream>
#include <string>

typedef struct {
    std::string a;
    std::string b;
} Info;

std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &o, const Info &rhs) {
    o << "Name: " << rhs.a << "\t" << rhs.b;
    return o;
}

#endif
```

This is how my main file looks like:

```
#include "InfoBuilder.hpp"
#include "myStructs.hpp"
#include <iostream>

// Overloading the operator exactly the same, but here works
// std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &o, const Info &rhs) {
//     o << "Name: " << rhs.a << "\t" << rhs.b;
//     return o;
// }

int main(){
    InfoBuilder s();

    std::cout << s.getArtistInfo("architects") << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Compiling this gives this error:

```
CMakeFiles/foo.dir/src/InfoBuilder.cpp.o: In function `operator<<(std::ostream&, Info const&)':
InfoBuilder.cpp:(.text+0x159): multiple definition of `operator<<(std::ostream&, Info const&)'
CMakeFiles/foo.dir/src/main.cpp.o:main.cpp:(.text+0xa4): first defined here
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/foo.dir/build.make:126: foo] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:68: CMakeFiles/foo.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:84: all] Error 2
```

Commenting the overloaded operator out in the `myStructs.hpp` file and just defining it in the `main.cpp` file works. But why does this make a difference as I am using include guards?
I also include `myStructs.hpp` in `InfoBuilder.hpp`.

Comment: You should only declare functions in a header, and define (implement) them in a source file; or else define them in a header with `inline` keyword.

Comment: Put an `inline` in front of the operator definition.

Answer (score 1):

You've got two options:

### Option 1: Put the implementation of your function in a cc file:

**myStructs.hpp**

```
#ifndef MY_STRUCTS_HPP
#define MY_STRUCTS_HPP

#include <iostream>
#include <string>

typedef struct {
    std::string a;
    std::string b;
} Info;

std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &o, const Info &rhs);

#endif
```

**myStructs.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "myStructs.hpp"

std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &o, const Info &rhs) {
    o << "Name: " << rhs.a << "\t" << rhs.b;
    return o;
}
```

### Option 2: Mark the function as static

**myStructs.hpp**

```
#ifndef MY_STRUCTS_HPP
#define MY_STRUCTS_HPP

#include <iostream>
#include <string>

typedef struct {
    std::string a;
    std::string b;
} Info;

static std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &o, const Info &rhs) {
    o << "Name: " << rhs.a << "\t" << rhs.b;
    return o;
}

#endif
```

Comment: Thanks, I decided to go for the static option, as I use the outstream operator mainly for debugging anyway. Can you explain, why it has to be static? Due to the include guard the method definition should be loaded only once. So how could it be defined multiple times?

Comment: It's defined once per compilation unit, but each cc file is a separate compilation unit.